# Execute a static synchronized method in parallel

Tags: java, synchronized

I'm using a thrid-party lib that has a static synchronized method, i want to execute this method in parallel without modifiying its source.

What can i do ?

Should i create an executor service with a thread factory that sets a new context class loader ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could certainly in theory load the library twice in separate class loaders. Practice might be more difficult.

In order to link to link to the copy in different class loaders you'll need to also load your code multiple times in those class loaders (or a child class loader). Common communication between the code instances should go through code loaded into a common base class. Keep reflection to an *absolute minimum*. Classes loaded by different class loaders will be incompatible even though they have the same name, which usually manifests as bizarre `ClassCastException`s. For instance, the runtime object and cast type have the same name. Following? Are you sure you want to do this?

Probably there is a reason why the method is synchronised. Probably the reason is really bad. There will be mutable statics in there. As you've loaded the code more than once there will be multiple copies of these mutable statics. If they are just caches that might not be too bad. However, the library almost certainly really sucks.

NB: **The thread context class loader has very little to do with anything except screwing things up.**

Answer (score 3):

A static synchronized method means its locked on the class. only one thread can grab the lock on the class. You can not even subclass this class at it won't allow you to override the static method.

I am afraid, you can not do anything.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to execute that method in parallel you would have to execute it in different process - i.e. run your program twice in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

If you load the class in two different class loaders, you can run the methods in each class loader independently.  However, I suspect the writer of the class had a good reason to make the method `static synchronized`  I would check this isn't actually required.